# Ionic 3- "ionic cordova build android" builds multiple apks

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to build android apk of my ionic app but it is building multiple apks but I just want only one apk i.e. "android-debug.apk".
anyone know what's the problem or what settings i need to do for this?

> result after running "ionic cordova build android":
>   [image: build result]

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is just because u have added crosswalk in your project just remove it your problem will be resolved.

Comment: @MahiParmar I didn't add it

Comment: your console says u have it in your project just find out with the command `cordova plugin list`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to generate a multi-APK application that uses Crosswalk for Pre-L devices, and the (updatable) system webview for L+. If you have To build System-webview apk, remove "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" plugin and run below command:

```
ionic cordova build android -- -- --minSdkVersion=21
```

Please find more details here https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I try by have error


`Task with path 'assembleArm64Debug' not found in root project 'android'.`